# ReloadData with expanded items not refreshing children

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsoutlineview

I have a simple `NSOutlineView` which works nice so far. The only thing I did not get to work is when I issue a `reloadData()`. Where I have an expanded item and the reason for the reload was that one child was added then the new child does not appear. The parent is refreshed as I see that the number of children (which I output too) is updated. The new child however does not appear.

I circumvented this behavior by collapsing the parent when adding or deleting child items. But I wonder if there is any trick to get the children get refreshed as well maintaining the expansion state of a parent as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use [reloadItem:reloadChildren:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOutlineView/reloadItem:reloadChildren:) on the NSOutlineView when you want to reload? If you want to refresh everything just reload the root item by passing 'nil' for the first parameter.

Comment: I was having a similar issue and this helped me.  Do you know if there is a way to prevent all rows with children from collapsing when this func is called?  I would like the rows that are expanded to remain expanded and any collapsed to remain collapsed, but this func and reloadData just collapses everything.