# NSOutlineView numberOfRows doesn't increase after reloadData

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I want to calculate the size of a cell that I've just added to an `NSOutlineView`. To do that, I add it to my data source, and then call `reloadData` on the `NSOutlineView`. For some reason, however, I can't examine the cell after `reloadData` for any but the very first row. The code looks like this:

```
[m_dataSource add:...];  // first add item to my data source
[m_outlineView reloadData];  

int nRows = (int) [m_outlineView numberOfRows];
NSCell *cell = [m_outlineView preparedCellAtColumn:0 row:nRows-1];
NSSize size = [cell cellSize];
```

For some reason, `nRows` is always 1 here, no matter how many rows I add. Thus, I can only ever query the size of the first cell in the very first row.

The behaviour I see might be related to the fact that the very first row is an expandable row and all other rows are children of the very first row. However, I have checked that

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item;
```

correctly returns `YES` for the item. Everything also appears correctly in the `NSOutlineView`. It's just that `numberOfRows` doesn't seem to get updated even though I call `reloadData` just before it.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReloadData with expanded items not refreshing children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548021/reloaddata-with-expanded-items-not-refreshing-children)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. Even when using `reloadItem:nil reloadChildren:YES` instead of `reloadData`,  `numberOfRows` still returns 1 and I'm unable to examine any cells except the ones in the first row.

Comment: Did you debug your datasource verifying the expected data - i.e. more than 1 item - is actually returned? Is it expanded? How many items are at root level?

Comment: @ATV: Oops, sorry, yeah, I was confusing the `isItemExpandable` method as indicating that a node should be expanded whereas it indicates only if a node is expandable. Manually expanding the nodes using `expandItem` solves the problem. Sorry for the confusion.